# PHP: Difficulties with sending a POST request to a .php file with curl

Tags: php, curl, http-post

I have a php file let's say `A.php` that gets some variables by `$_POST` method and updates a local database.

Another php file with the name `dataGather.php` gathers the data in the correct form and after that it tries to send the data to the local database by using the `A.php` file. Note that both files are in the same directory.

The code where I use the curl functions to do the `POST` request is the following:

```
    $url = "A.php";
    $ch = curl_init();
    $curlConfig = array(
        CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
        CURLOPT_POST           => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $datatopost
    );
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
```

`$datatopost`

is an array like the following:

```
$datatopost = array (
       "value1" => $val1,
       "value2" => $val2,
        etc
 }
```

The problem is that when I run my program I get the following result:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in 
        C:\xampp\htdocs\dataGather.php on line 97
```

does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks in advance

PS: The file `A.php` is 100% correct because I have tested it by gathering the information needed with javascript. It informs the database the way I want. Also the array `$datatopost` has all the information in the correct form.

Comment: so it's taking too long to respond. Have you tried posting it outside of the call, from a web page for example to see if it just ticks away?

Comment: yes I tried to see if it collects the information and it does in less than a second, I have even printed all the information to see if it's the correct form.

Inside datagather I use the POST method to save the data in the local database.

I tried running it under localhost, would it be different if I run it on a web page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you directly run your php script without using a web server but by simply starting the script as executable. This is suggested by the fact that you have an absolute path in your error message. Whilst it is absolutely fine to run a php script like that you have to ask yourself: what does that cURL call actually make? It does *not* open and run the php file `A.php` you tried to reference. Why not? Because cURL opens *URLs*, not files. And without using a server that can react to url requests (ike a http server), what do you expect to happen?

The error you get is a timeout, since cURL tries to contact a http server. Since you did not specify a valid URL it most likely falls back to 'localhost'. but there is not server listening there...

Comment: thank you very much that was indeed the problem!!

I changed the $url to "http://localhost//...//A.php" and it worked! Wow it's almost 2 am, I can't believe I wasted 2 hours for this.